# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle to_timestamp_tz()

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I would like to know how I can translate this Oracle line into SQL Server code:

```
to_timestamp_tz('18/08/14 09:43:29,262000000 +02:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`convert()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to [**`datetimeoffset()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) by replacing the comma with a period, and specifying a style that matches day first (if not already implicitly set by session settings and/or session language settings):

```
declare @str varchar(40) = '18/08/14 09:43:29,262000000 +02:00';
select convert(datetimeoffset(7),replace(@str,',','.'),4)
```

Or setting [**`set dateformat dmy`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql):

```
set dateformat dmy;
select convert(datetimeoffset(7),replace(@str,',','.'))
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GSGL61143